# Passing custom build output path to gcc (makefile)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I've just started learning Makefile and I'm trying to compile a C program with it.

Here's my script:

```
CC   = gcc
FILE = main.c
APP  = my_app.exe
PATH = "C:\DATA\$(APP)"

generate:
    $(CC) $(FILE) -o $(PATH)
```

The above script when executed generates the following output:

```
gcc main.c -o "C:\DATA\my_app.exe"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc main.c -o C:\DATA\my_app.exe, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:7: generate] Error 2
```

But it works when I hardcode the path in the command as follows:

```
CC   = gcc
FILE = main.c
APP  = my_app.exe

generate:
    $(CC) $(FILE) -o "C:\DATA\$(APP)"
```

I'm working on Windows OS.

What is the issue here? Why can't I pass the same path using a variable?

Comment: `PATH` is a special variable that holds the set of directories that the shell will search when you run a program.  When you reset that variable, you're changing where the shell will search to only that one file which means nothing (including your compiler) can be found.  Use a different variable name, not `PATH`.

Comment: Suggestion: Call it `TARGET`.

Comment: @MadScientist It works, it's exactly as you said :)